# need help understanding the C++ code

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I came across this piece of code in "C++ Templates - The complete Guide". I tried my best to find out if this has been explained somewhere. Apologies if it has already been explained

```
template<int I> void f(int (&)[24/(4-I)]);
template<int I> void f(int (&)[24/(4+I)]);
int main()
{
    &f<4>; // ERROR: division by zero (SFINAE doesn't apply)
}
```

Book does say that this won't compile for a specific reason but I do not understand the template syntax and how the function is called with & operator at the beginning.

Appreciate the help.

Harish

Comment: The `&` operator is just taking the address of the `f<4>` function and discarding it without actually invoking it.  This causes the template `f<4>` to be instantiated, but not called.  In this case it is used simply to see if the template `f<4>` can be instantiated at all.

Comment: @cdhowie: Thank you. That helps me with the &f<4> part. still I am confused with the template syntax template<int I> void f(int (&)[24/(4-I)]); Is this a reference to an integer array of size determined by template parameter I ?

Comment: `24/0` is not a valid constant expression. Array sizes need to be valid constant expressions.

Comment: @HarishRamanathan *"Is this a reference to an integer array of size determined by template parameter I ?"* It is the declaration of a function taking such a reference, but otherwise yes, that is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it does compile. You can also call one of these functions, e.g. the following prints `+`:

```
template<int I> void f(int (&)[24/(4-I)]) { std::cout << "-" << std::endl; }
template<int I> void f(int (&)[24/(4+I)]) { std::cout << "+" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    int a[3];
    f <4>(a);
}
```

Anyhow, both template functions `f` expect a reference to an `int` array, whose length depends on template parameter `I`. For instance, I picked `a[3]` because `24/(4+I) = 24/8 = 3` for `I=4`.

The function is not called by `&f<4>`, but only instantiated by taking its address (which actually issues a warning for the unused result).

I guess the book assumes the code won't compile due to the division by zero caused by attempting to instantiate the first overload for `I=4`, which is not the case.

Comment: The OP's code doesn't compile (GCC 4.7.3), because SFINAE doesn't apply, as it's noted.

Comment: I checked with gcc 4.8.1 and clang 3.3, which bot compile.

Comment: Well, that code as well... only issue is clang's warning "expression result unused".

Comment: @iavr I was using a outdated compiler. However, the output message was weird, I thought... "statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function " 
With gcc 4.8.1 it compiles fine..